how to filter rows in r in a dataframe with multiple columns based on names in a column from another dataframe?
I have a two dataframes of names, where dataframe one contains a single column of names whereas dataframe two contains multiple columns of names. How can I filter the second dataframe to only contain rows that have a match in the first dataframe?
ex/
df1



names




John


Joan



df2



Column A
Column B
Column C
Column D




Gerry
Jim
Brian
Joan


John
John
John
John


Ron
Greg
Sam
Maisy



desired output



names
Column A
Column B
Column C
Column D




Joan
Gerry
Jim
Brian
Joan


John
John
John
John
John



I've tried using a left_join from dplyr but the output was not what I needed

In your desired output, including the first column from df1 doesn't make a lot of sense since if you have "Joan" in column B row 2 instead of "John", and "John" instead of "Jim" in row 1, then there is no unique correspondence to the rows of df2 (you could easily argue that the first column should have "John" and "Joan" instead of "Joan" and "John").

One way is to find the rows of df2 that match the names of df1 and use the unique indices to index df2.
df2[unique(unlist(lapply(1:ncol(df2), \(x) which(df2[,x] %in% df1$name)))),]


      A    B     C    D
2  John John  John John
1 Gerry  Jim Brian Joan

This gives you a filtered dataframe that "only contains rows that have a match in the first dataframe", as requested.

Data:
df1 <- structure(list(name = c("John", "Joan")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

df2 <- structure(list(A = c("Gerry", "John", "Ron"), B = c("Jim", "John", 
"Greg"), C = c("Brian", "John", "Sam"), D = c("Joan", "John", 
"Maisy")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))


library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
             names = c("John", "Joan")
)


df2 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
          Column.A = c("Gerry", "John", "Ron"),
          Column.B = c("Jim", "John", "Greg"),
          Column.C = c("Brian", "John", "Sam"),
          Column.D = c("Joan", "John", "Maisy")
)

df2 %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  pivot_longer(-rowname) %>% 
  filter(any(df1$names %in% value), .by = rowname) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = rowname, names_from = name, values_from = value)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   rowname Column.A Column.B Column.C Column.D
#>   <chr>   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
#> 1 1       Gerry    Jim      Brian    Joan    
#> 2 2       John     John     John     John

Created on 2024-09-10 with reprex v2.0.2
